# how to insert data from edit text to sqlite db in android application

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am currently working on an android application where i have to register new users into sqlite db and users enter their details into editText and we need to fectch entered data and store it in db

the thing is when i try it with hard coded data it works fine.

DBHelper.java

```
package com.example.db;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String  DBNAME = "login.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create TABLE users(unsername TEXT primary key,password TEXT,fullName TEXT,email TEXT,phone TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists users");
    }

    public void insertData(String username, String password, String fullName, String email,String phone) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("unsername",username);
        contentValues.put("password",password);
        contentValues.put("fullName",fullName);
        contentValues.put("email",email);
        contentValues.put("phone",phone);

    }
}
```

here is signup.java activity

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.UserHandle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.util.Pair;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;



public class SignUpPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Varaible
    Button loginbtn, signupbtn;
    ImageView logo;
    TextInputLayout uname, pass, mail, phoneNo, fname;

    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_page);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        loginbtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        signupbtn = findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);
        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
        uname = findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.pwd);
        phoneNo = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        mail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        fname = findViewById(R.id.name);

        String username = uname.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String fullNmae = fname.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String email = mail.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String phone = phoneNo.getEditText().getText().toString();


        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpPage.this, LoginPage.class);
                Pair[] pair = new Pair[3];
                pair[0] = new Pair<View, String>(logo, "logo_img");
                pair[1] = new Pair<View, String>(loginbtn, "sign_up_in");
                pair[2] = new Pair<View, String>(signupbtn, "back_sign_up_in");

                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SignUpPage.this, pair);
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        });

        signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean insert =  dbHelper.insertData(username,password,fullNmae,email,phone);
                    if (insert)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpPage.this,"Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpPage.this,"not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                

            }
        });


    }

}
```

here all id like uname,fname,pass are TextInputLayout in which TextInputEditText is present

as mentioned above when i try passing "username" as chard coded strings the function work fine

```
 String[] usernames = {"john_doe", "jane_smith", "bob_jackson"};
        String[] passwords = {"StrongPassword123", "SecurePass456", "Pa$$w0rd789"};
        String[] fullNames = {"John Doe", "Jane Smith", "Bob Jackson"};
        String[] emails = {"john.doe@example.com", "jane.smith@example.com", "bob.jackson@example.com"};
        String[] phones = {"123-456-7890", "987-654-3210", "555-123-4567"};

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

// Insert data into the database
        for (int i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
            dbHelper.insertData(usernames[i], passwords[i], fullNames[i], emails[i], phones[i]);
        }
```

what i want is that when users enter their detail in TextInputEditText when signup btn is clicked all the data should be stored in String variable and dbinsert function should be called inserting all data into db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read values from inputs at the button press time, not in `onCreate()`. So move `input.getEditText().getText().toString()` code under `onClick()` like:

```
signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    String username = uname.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String password = pass.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String fullNmae = fname.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String email = mail.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String phone = phoneNo.getEditText().getText().toString();
    
    // ...
    boolean insert =  dbHelper.insertData(username,password,fullNmae,email,phone);
    // ...
  }
});
```